# Can we keep values of a HashMap in memory even after java code is terminated?

Tags: java

A particular HashMap contains information which will be used by three Java codes (b.java, c.java and d.java). a.java is another code which puts variables inside that HashMap. Now, I want that HashMap to be used by these three java codes. As, after termination of a.java, the HashMap is lost, I am unable to do it. I dont want to use file writing and reading to make the system faster. What way I can achieve it using Java?

Comment: Do they all run in the same JVM instance? Or do they run independently?

Comment: Do they run at the same time?

Comment: They run serially, one after another. I just want to keep that Hasmap alive in memory for faster use.

Comment: Ok, serially. In the same JVM instance?

Comment: If it's the same instance, the easiest thing to do is make it `static`.

Comment: Do you mean pass map to one class to another? is it so?

Comment: Sounds like its time to e.java so you can start think of in memory caching solutions

Comment: Please provide the method signatures of the relevant public methods and the relevant part of the main method - or better a SSCCE

Comment: Are they run serially in the same thread or multiple threads or executed externally in different JVM instances?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, try using a Properties file, or SQLite database, to store the values, and make sure that the reading/writing is going to be a bottleneck before you spend time optimising for performance.

If you're already there, then it's important to be at peace that when the Java process ends, all memory allocated is released. So if you want to retain it in memory, then there must be a process associated. You've got a multitude of options, a couple that spring to mind are either run a memcache/redis process, or run an ehcache/hazelcast process which each of your codes connect to. I assume you're looking for something lighter-weight than running a database to host this information.

With memcache or redis you'd write your key-value pairs and read them using a network protocol.
With ehcache/hazelcast you'd write and read a DistributedMap, and the library takes care of getting the information inter-process.

The end result is the same: A separate process from your existing code, which serves to keep the values resident in memory for the transient code to access. A side benefit of this is that your code doesn't need to run on the same machine, which is a limitation if they're all in the same VM or they're using a file to persist the data (unless the file is on a network share!)

Answer (score 2):

If you start your different Java programs with another Java program one after another it should not be a problem. Just init your HashMap in the executor class and set it to a static Variable in the other programs.

```
public class A{
    public static HashMap<String,String> hashMap;     
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
} 
[class B, class C]

public class ProgrammRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        A.hashMap = hashMap;
        A.main(new String[]{});
        B.hashMap = hashMap;
        B.main(new String[]{});
        [...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution should be serialize your map in fileSystem (if you don't want to use **caching libraries or Databases** inclusively your map shouldn't contain non primitive DataTypes, you may require to write your code if you are author of the class or more worst if those are Third-Party API interfaces.)

you can easily test this:

1. Set read flag to **false**; it will serialize your map into specified location.
2. Set read flag to **true**;it will read previously serialized map

In your Programs **you can use these read() and write()** methods.

```
public class PersistHashMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean read = false;
        if (read == false) {
            write();
        } else {
            Map<Integer, String> map = read();
            for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("key:" + entry.getKey() + "----- value:" + entry.getValue());
            }
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Map<Integer, String> read() {
        Map<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\hashmap.ser")) {

            try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {

                hmap=(HashMap<Integer,String>)ois.readObject();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return hmap;
    }

    public static void write() {
        Map<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        // Adding elements to HashMap
        hmap.put(1, "1");
        hmap.put(2, "2");
        hmap.put(3, "3");
        hmap.put(4, "4");
        hmap.put(5, "5");

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\hashmap.ser")) {

            try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
                oos.writeObject(hmap);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what do you mean by *"after java code is terminated"*.

If you run B, C and D in the same thread serially. Create a HashMap and pass it to B, C and D.

If B, C and D are 3 Java Applications executed separately. You could use an InMemory Database like HSQLDB. Or even better, think about migrating B, C and D into one java application.

Answer (score -1):

If it is running in 3 different JVM's then you cannot use it in other program.
You should persist the data to the database or write to the file!!

Comment: Remote Method Invocation, anybody?